# SQL Queries problems

Tags: sql, database

So I'm new to this site because I just recently started a data basing class, so I'm still learning the basics, but I need a little bit of help. So these are the two problems I have.

List of all apartments that were occupied on March 1, 2015 sorted by complex and apartment number. Example Results:

```
complexName apartmentNumber
Fox Run      101
Fox Run      102
Fox Run      204
Oak Meadows  103
Villa Maria  11
Villa Maria  12
```

List of all tenants that had a current lease on March 1, 2015 sorted by property and apartment number
Example results:

```
complexName apartmentNumber givenName   familyName
Fox Run      101             Shannon    McCoy
Fox Run      102             Larry      Thomas
Fox Run      204             Mark       Patterson
Oak Meadows  103             Jose       Ortiz
Villa Maria  11              Cassie     Lee
Villa Maria  12              Robert     Woodward
```

My SQL for the first problem is...

```
SELECT DISTINCT name AS 'complexName', number AS 'apartmentNumber'
FROM week9wildwood.Complex AS c
INNER JOIN week9wildwood.Apartment AS a ON c.complexID = a.Complex_complexID
INNER JOIN week9wildwood.Lease AS l ON a.number = l.Apartment_number
WHERE startDate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2016-03-01'
ORDER BY name, number;
```

But I keep getting this back...

```
complexName apartmentNumber
Fox Run      102
Fox Run      103
Fox Run      104
Oak Meadows  102
Oak Meadows  103
Villa Maria  11
Villa Maria  21
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and why it's coming back with different data.  I also feel like the querie for the first problem, is almost the same for the second problem, but the wording of it has me hesitant.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To find out which ones were occupied on a specific date, you'd clearly have to use both the date they started their occupancy and the date they *ended it*, wouldn't you? And where did your arbitrary `2015-03-01` and `2016-03-01` come from? What about someone who moved in on 2015-01-01 and left on 2015-12-31? Wouldn't they also occupy it on 2015-03-01?

Comment: The reason why I chose those dates was because I thought it would include anybody who had their lease still going through 2015-03-01.  In the database I'm working on for school, there are only 2 apartments that started on 2015-03-01, but I need the ones that have their leases going through that date.

Comment: That's no reason to make up arbitrary dates. Read the first sentence in my previous comment again.

Comment: I was trying to figure it out just now but had no luck, so how would I use both  the date they started and the date they ended if I don't use two arbitrary numbers?

Comment: `WHERE startdate <= '2015-03-01' and enddate >= '2015-03-01'` Come on. Think about things. How would you do it if you had a list of leases with start and end dates on a piece of paper in front of you?

Comment: I think there is an issue with this condition "week9wildwood.Lease AS l ON a.number = l.Apartment_number" . The Apartment number is going to repeat in all complex. I mean there will 102 in Fox run as well as in Oak Meadows. So this will result in wrong joins. Do you have complex id stored in Lease table. if yes add an additional condition of "c. complexID =l. complexID".

Comment: @KenWhite  I finally figured it out.  I took what you suggested, but I added  "AND DATE(DATE_ADD(lease.startdate, interval (lease.duration) month))" between the startdate and enddate.  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: You shouldn't need the DATEADD at all, and if you do something is wrong, either with your data or your SQL.

Comment: Well now I'm definitely lost. Granted this is only my second week of actually working with SQL, using DATE_ADD was the only way I could figure out how to get the desired outcome.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but maybe just make sure the end date is greater than March 15, 2015

```
select name AS 'complexName', number AS 'apartmentNumber'
from week9wildwood.Complex AS c
inner join
 week9wildwood.Apartment AS a
on c.complexID = a.Complex_complexID
inner join
 week9wildwood.Lease AS l
on a.number = l.Apartment_number
where end_date > 2015-03-15
ORDER BY name, number;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Group By?

```
SELECT DISTINCT name AS 'complexName', number AS 'apartmentNumber' 
FROM week9wildwood.Complex c 
INNER JOIN week9wildwood.Apartment a
ON c.complexID = a.Complex_complexID 
INNER JOIN week9wildwood.Lease l 
ON a.number = l.Apartment_number 
WHERE startDate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2016-03-01' 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY name, number;
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it came back as 
    complexName apartmentName
    Fox Run           102
    Oak Meadows  102
    Villa Maria        21